# Viewport Render and Image Render look different - Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

When trying to render an image in blender, the rendered output looks different to the render mode in my viewport. I am using Cycles

[image]

In the viewport, the glass is dark and not entirely transparent, and the decal on the window is projected using 'shrinkwrap' onto the glass.
[image]
However, in the render view, the glass is mostly transparent, and the decal is no longer projected onto the glass, and instead is floating above.

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

So i dont really have a an answer but for some reason when i hid the rear glass, then un-hid it, it showed up in a different location. i proceeded to move it back to where it was supposed to go and the issue was solved... not sure why, or how, but it seems i have accidently fixed my issue